# How to simulate picking a random photon from an entire emission spectrum

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that will simulate a photon being emitted from this
[Emission spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONYks.png)

If I run this code a million times, the resultant energies of the photons should be able to reproduce said graph, but each one should be random. It doesn't need to be highly accurate, it is just for an approximation. I am writing this in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to discretize the distribution first. For example, instead of picking from the continuous interval [0, 60.5), you'll pick from the discrete set of values `[0, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 60.49]`. (The shape of your distribution will tell you how precise each value needs to be.)

Next, you need to associate a *weight* to each value. That's just the y-value at the given x-coordinate.

Finally, use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) to choose an `x` value according to the weights selected above.